# Checking input is a sum in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have a form where the user can type something and I want my script to check if it's a sum (e.g. 5 x 5 or 3+ 3) how would I do this?  Presumably using Regular Expressions?

Comment: How complex will these arithmetic operations be? If they're gonna be more complex then your examples, regular expressions will probably not be the solution. You will probably have to use/write a parser (which could utilize regular expressions) that tokenizes the input. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis

Answer (score 4):

If you mean an "arithmetic operation", it would be something like (including floating point numbers)

```
preg_match('/-?\d+(\.\d+)?\h*[-+x\/]\h*-?\d+(\.\d+)?/', $input);
```

Comment: preg_match('/-?\d+(\.\d+)*\h*[-+x\/]-?\d+(\.\d+)*/', $input); will catch negative numbers too.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about checking that this is a sum, but you are writting a product!
If you want to check a sum, then accept only numbers and "+" sign :

```
preg_match('/^[ +0-9]+$/', $expression);
```

Comment: Probably want more structure than that. That regex would match things like `"+09 ++"`, which is obviously not a sum.

Comment: true, but I think he might use a kind of parser to evaluate his expression, so it was just a very small test.
But soulmerge answer is much better :-)